# Is there a way to reorganize UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

When adding controllers to a storyboard, they show randomly in the storyboard sidebar list. Is there a way to reorder controllers to be in a preferred sequence?

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Nope, I have tried when I started iOS development. but there is no way to do so. The view controller get added in List based on its ID in XML.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it too dodgy to play with these IDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use more storyboards. There are many articles around listing the benefits. And even libraries to allow cross storyboard segues if you really need them.

Among the advantages, better overall view, semantical separation of different 'stories', more lightweight storyboards for older machines or interface builders, smaller ones for little screens of a laptop, so much better for git and code collaboration and no overhead, nor relevant cons (mostly).

[some more info](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/02/18/ios-storyboards-xcode5/)

Comment: In my current project, I have approximately 10 storyboards. Each of these has about 10 view controllers and some navigation controllers. So I'm almost ready to make sub-sub storyboards... +1 for helping

Comment: Oh that sucks :/ by the way there are ways to make also sub-storyboards :D using a fake view controller as a placeholder for another storyboard. Some of the mentioned libraries provide that. But i fully agree it would be really nice to have a way to order them ( not to mention better zooming and other IB organizational issues)